# How to export data from ListLogLogPlot

Tags: export, data

I have a `ListLogLogPlot`, for example:

```
data1 = ListLogLogPlot[Table[{i^2, i^(1/3)}, {i, 1, 20, 1}]]
```

**Note:** I know that there is no need to export the data in the example, because the data are explicit as specified in the `Table`, however, in my real problem, the data in Table are calculated from the other data, which are not explicit. Thus, I try to export the data using the following code into a .txt or .dat file for the subsequent processing.

```
datapart1 = Cases[data1, Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];

Export["datapart1.txt", datapart1, "Table"]
```

However, the first line gives me an error:

> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>

Accordingly, the export gives just an empty file.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  `ListLogLogPlot` *always* takes data that is explicitly specified as data points.  If you already have this data, why can't you export it directly?  If you don't already have this data, how can you use `ListLogLogPlot` at all?

Comment: I understood this such that you somehow produce a list. In your example above this list is given by  `lst=Table[{i^2, i^(1/3)}, {i, 1, 20, 1}] ` , but in a real case - by a much more complex procedure, right? Then you need to make another list out of it, such that it can be plotted as a log-log plot. Am I right? If so, you can do a simple trick. After you have created a list `lst` do the following: `lst/.{x_,y_}->{Log[x],Log[y]} ` . Done. This you may export. Have fun!

Comment: Hi, @ Alexei Boulbitch, you got the point of my problem. Trying it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, in this case you don't have to even use a replacement rule, you can just use `Log[lst]` since `Log` is `Listable`.

Comment: Based on the comments the OP effectively wanted to use `ListLogLogPlot` to *compute* (not plot) the logarithm of the data.  As Jason notes, this should be done with `Log` instead.  Voting to close as simple mistake.  Please clarify if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get `Cases` of `Line` in your plot.  There are no lines in your plot, only points.

```
data1 = 
  ListLogLogPlot[Table[{i^2, i^(1/3)}, {i, 1, 20, 1}]];
Cases[data1, Point[data_] :> data, Infinity]
(* {{{0., 0.}, {1.38629, 0.231049}, {2.19722, 
   0.366204}, {2.77259, 0.462098}, {3.21888, 0.536479}, {3.58352, 
   0.597253}, {3.89182, 0.648637}, {4.15888, 0.693147}, {4.39445, 
   0.732408}, {4.60517, 0.767528}, {4.79579, 0.799298}, {4.96981, 
   0.828302}, {5.1299, 0.854983}, {5.27811, 0.879686}, {5.4161, 
   0.902683}, {5.54518, 0.924196}, {5.66643, 0.944404}, {5.78074, 
   0.963457}, {5.88888, 0.98148}, {5.99146, 0.998577}}} *)
```

You had originally used a `[[1]]` in your code, which for just one plotted list had the effect of removing some extraneous curly brackets.  But for multiple plotted lists, it takes just the first list.  Without the `[[1]]`, it is more general,

```
Cases[
 ListLogLogPlot[Table[{i^2, i^(1/3 + m)}, {m, 0, 4, 1}, {i, 1, 20, 1}]]
 , Point[data_] :> data, Infinity]
(* {{{0., 0.}, {1.38629, 0.231049}, {2.19722, 
   0.366204}, {2.77259, 0.462098},............
   ......................... {5.78074, 12.5249}, {5.88888, 
   12.7592}, {5.99146, 12.9815}}} *)
```

Of course, as Szabolcs pointed out, you can get the same thing by typing

```
N @ Log @ Table[{i^2, i^(1/3 + m)}, {m, 0, 4, 1}, {i, 1, 20, 1}]
```

Comment: @ Jason B, thanks. Can I change `Line` into `Point` within `Cases` to export the point coordinates? Because my `ListLogLogPlot` takes very long time to generate the curve.

Comment: @W.Robin that works as well.  As long as you have the plot in a notebook you can extract the underlying points.

Comment: @ Jason B, there are 5 `Table` in my `ListLogLogPlot`, they are placed in a bracket as `{Table1, Table2, ..., Table5}`. Use `Cases[data1, Point[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]]`, it can only export part of the points, seems only those in the first `Table`. Help...

Comment: Right on, that's because of the 1 you gave as the fourth argument to `Cases` and also because of the `[[1]]` you had at the end.  see the update above.